# Write a text file with tab delimiter in .Net Core

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, text-files, asp.net-core-2.2

Hi do you have any guides, work aid or step by step how to export to text with tab delimited. Im using Asp.Net Core 2.2 MVC EF. I want to export a list from my
[table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uaIV.png). I want to have a button where the user click in this DownloadFile Action will trigger.

```
public object DownloadFile()
        {
            var payments = new List<BdoPE>
            {
                new BdoPE
                {
                    DocDateInDoc = "01/01/2019",
                    DocType = "DZ",
                    CompanyCode = "3000",
                    PosDateInDoc = "01/01/2019",
                    FiscalPeriod = "01",
                    CurrentKey = "PHP",
                    RefDocNum = "Over-The-Counter",
                    DocHeadT = "BDO",
                    PosKeyInNextLine = "40",
                    AccMatNextLine = "11231131",
                    AmountDocCur = "0000000010050",
                    ValDate = "01/01/2019",
                    AssignNum = "EEA",
                    ItemText = "1000136212  ",
                    PosKeyInNextLine2 = "15",
                    AccMatNextLine2 = "0115027FF",
                    AmountDocCur2 = "0000000010050",
                    BaseDateDueCal = "01/01/2019",
                    ItemText2 = "1000136212"
                },
            };

            // I want this part to let the user select where they want to save the text file.
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.txt")) // not static location like this one.

            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
            {
                csv.WriteHeader<BdoPE>();
                csv.WriteRecord(payments);
            }

            // where should i put the delimiter part?

            return; // to what?
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use this package https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

You can easily write a text file with tab delimiter.

```
using CsvHelper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var records = new List<Foo>
            {
                new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
            };

            var configuration = new CsvHelper.Configuration.Configuration()
            {
                Delimiter = "\t"
            };

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, configuration))
            {
                csv.WriteRecords(records);
            }
        }

        public class Foo
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using this to upload files but I can't find in documentation how to write text file.

Comment: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/writing/write-class-objects/

Comment: Hi @JeePakaJP but the output is comma delimited not tab delimited.

Comment: Set Delimiter property in Configuration 
https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/Configuration

Comment: I'll try this one

Comment: You should not, create an another question